# Insert all rows from one table to another + time stamp at the end

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a change log db that's the exact same as my active db except it has a changedate DATE field at the end.

The db is basically one primary key id, and about 50 other columns of various data types. The script I have in php is it tries to insert new ids and if it gets the error message for duplicate primary key, then it should get that row, insert it into my backup db with a curdate() call as the final date value, delete the entry from my first db, then insert the new entry.

I have all the other parts of the script finished except the part where I have to insert everything from the first table + an extra column for curdate(). Or if there's a better solution to my problem of inserting into a backup database when a duplicate primary key comes in when there's a fairly high amount of rows please share that.

Comment: can you show some code? IF you are overwriting a existing set of Cols in your DB you need to use UPDATE, not INSERT or it will fail. As for the current date, you can use "NOW()" in your mysql query

Comment: Do you mean the delete and insert code? It's just delete from table where id=someid and then insert into table values (etc.) One problem with update is that I can't figure out how to update all columns without explicitly stating all of their names.

Comment: I believe you can have a timestamp type field that gets the current timestamp automatically if you pass NULL to it, I haven't used MySQL in 4 years or so, so I don't know for sure anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do an INSERT INTO SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO `backupTable` SELECT *, NOW() FROM `originalTable` WHERE id = '$id';
```

You have to specify the `ID` for the entry you wish to copy to your backup db. <strike>You have also to be sure, that the `ID`is not already in your backup table. You can use `REPLACE INTO` to workaround this case.</strike>

```
REPLACE INTO `backupTable` SELECT *, NOW() FROM `originalTable` WHERE id = '$id';
```

Comment: oh, forgot to mention that backup table's id isn't a primary key since it's more of a change log than a backup table, I just need to know whenever something new is entering. Insert should be fine right?

Answer (score 2):

basicly, you can create a `TIMESTAMP` column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value.
when you insert a row to that table, the current date/time will be automaticly inserted.
is that what you were looking for ?

BTW: i would recommend to kill the problem at it source and make sure a duplicate primary key will not be inserted to the datatable..
to do that, you can use the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: Thanks, both solutions worked though what I wanted to do is if a duplicate id came in and if it was different then insert into change log etc.

Comment: you are handling a duplicate id as an error, while in the first place it should have not get a duplicate.